# Illustrator: Eliminating The Center Of The Text

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a word repeated four times with a star over the middle of the text. Is there a way to eliminate just the letters behind the star?

[image]

Comment: Yes, but how that depends on your situation and file structure

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can't you simply set the fill of the star to white?  It might be better if you show a screen shot demonstrating what you are trying to do/what problem you are trying to solve, or what has failed, and also mention what you are going to use this for.   Is it for print, on-screen use, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the update. So now, try setting the star's fill to white.  Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've added a photo for reference. I've tried grouping them together and using every Pathfinder tool. I've also tried the same thing with everything ungrouped.  I've tried using the eraser tool as well. I'm somewhat of a beginner, used this software in the past and freshening up. My end purpose is to do a vinyl cut so I'm trying to eliminate the words in the middle all together. Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: And do you want to keep the yellow star outline?

Comment: Yes, if possible.

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a try. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the text and convert to outlines by doing *Object > Expand*
2. Ungroup until there are no groups left, and do *Object > Compound Path > Make*
3. Select the star and copy it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
4. Select the star and text, and in the Path Finder hit the *Minus Front* button. Note: this boolean operation will consume the star, but don't worry
5. Do *Edit > Paste in Front*, to get the star back.